# rails has_many at least one children has the value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let say I have a `Group` of `User`s and `User` has a enum, which described it's mood.

```
class Group < AR::Base
  has_many :users

class User < AR::Base
  belongs_to :group
  enum mood: %i(good bad ugly)
```

How can I find all groups, where at least one `User` has the good mood?

Which index should I add for optimizing this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `joins` method.

```
Group.joins(:users).where("users.mood = ?", User.moods[:good])
```

You can add this into your migration

```
add_index :users, :group_id
```

Comment: Which index should I add?

Comment: There is `add_index` method. Which columns should I add for fasterize this query?